# Symfony 3 service not found exception

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

I have a Tree like this:

```
src
`-- AppBundle  
    |-- AppBundle.php   
    |-- Controller   
    |   `-- MyController.php  
    `-- Service         
        `-- MyStringService.php
```

Now I want to use the service "MyStringService" in "MyController" like this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Date;
use Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Cloner\Data;

class MyController extends Controller 
{
    public function usernameAction(Request $request, $username)
    {
        $data = $this->get('my_string_service')->getString($username);
        return $this->render('profile.html.twig', $data);
    }
}
```

So let's look at the service, that does basically nothing:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Service;

class MyStringService 
{

    public function getString($string)
    {
        return $string;
    }

}
```

And so that I can call it by the ID I have following in my services.yml:

```
services:
    my_string_service:
        class: AppBundle/Service/MyStringService
```

When I use `php bin/console debug:container my_string_service` I get:

```
Information for Service "my_string_service"
===========================================

 ---------------- ----------------------------------- 
  Option           Value
---------------- ----------------------------------- 
  Service ID       my_string_service                  
  Class            AppBundle/Service/MyStringService  
  Tags             -                                  
  Public           no                                 
  Synthetic        no                                 
  Lazy             no                                 
  Shared           yes                                
  Abstract         no
  Autowired        yes                                
  Autoconfigured   yes
---------------- -----------------------------------
```

Now when I start the service and open the page `localhost:8000/` or `localhost:8000/MyUsername` I get an `ServiceNotFoundException`.

So now I just started with symfony and do not know what I am missing.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: why `public no` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key item here in the output is `Public no`.

By default, with a fresh Symfony installation, services are private, with the intent on having them used as dependencies rather than fetching from the container (so, type-hinted via a constructor, or with a little extra config, in a ControllerAction).

You can either declare that service as `public: true` in your services.yml file, or (better, long term), start to define them in a constructor:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use AppBundle\Service\MyStringService

class MyStringService 
{
    private $strService;

    public function __constructor(MyStringService $strService)
    {
        $this->strService = $strService;
    }

    public function getString($string)
    {
        $data = $this->strService->getString($username);
        return $this->render('profile.html.twig', $data);
        ...
```

There is documentation on the [service_container page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#public-versus-private-services).

Comment: Thanks for that... Now I can work on an Invalidname `"'AppBundle/Service/MyStringService'" is not a valid class name for the "my_string_service" service.`

Comment: It's a \namespace\class name